# Texture mapping of the cessna.osg via GLSL shaders

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, 3d, glsl, openscenegraph

What I am trying to do should be pretty simple, I guess, but I am not getting what I want (maybe because I am kind of newbie in this kind of tools). I just want to map a certain texture image (typical bricks, for instance) into the existing cessna.osg, via vertex and fragment shaders. To do the task, I chose a very simple vertex and fragment shader, which, in my limited understanding, should work, but it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
#include <osg/PositionAttitudeTransform>   
#include <osgDB/ReadFile>   
#include <osgDB/FileUtils>   
#include <osgGA/TrackballManipulator>   
#include <osg/Program>   
#include <osg/Shader>   
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>   
#include <iostream>   
#include <osg/Texture2D>   

static const char* VertexShader = {
    "varying vec2 texCoords;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   texCoords = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;\n"
    "   gl_Position = ftransform();\n"
    "}\n"
};

static const char* FragmentShader = {
    "varying vec2 texCoords;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D tex;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, texCoords);\n"
    "}\n"
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Assembling scenegraph
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> model = osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg");

    // Assigning program
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::StateSet> ss = model->getOrCreateStateSet();
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Program> program(new osg::Program);
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Shader> vShader(new osg::Shader(osg::Shader::VERTEX, VertexShader));
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Shader> fShader(new osg::Shader(osg::Shader::FRAGMENT, FragmentShader));
    program->addShader(vShader);
    program->addShader(fShader);
    ss->setAttributeAndModes(program.get());

    //Set Texture 1
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Texture2D> bodyTexture = new osg::Texture2D;
    bodyTexture->setImage(osgDB::readImageFile("Images/Brick-Norman-Brown.TGA"));

    bodyTexture->setWrap(osg::Texture::WRAP_S, osg::Texture::REPEAT);
    bodyTexture->setWrap(osg::Texture::WRAP_T, osg::Texture::REPEAT);
    bodyTexture->setFilter(osg::Texture::MIN_FILTER, osg::Texture::LINEAR);
    bodyTexture->setFilter(osg::Texture::MAG_FILTER, osg::Texture::LINEAR);

    ss->setTextureAttributeAndModes(0, bodyTexture.get());
    ss->addUniform(new osg::Uniform("tex", 0));

    // View the scene
    osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
    viewer.setSceneData(model);
    viewer.setUpViewInWindow(0, 0, 512, 384);
    return viewer.run();

    return 0;
}
```

What I get is the cessna model with a plain color (the main color of the texture image), but I never get a actual "texturized" cessna.

My apologizes if the question is very stupid, but I really appreciate any kind of hint that help keep moving.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: In this example I am using OpenGL, but the idea is to learn how to do exactly the same thing in Open GL ES 2.0 later on (but right now I am more interested in OpenGL)

Comment: Are you sure that the `cessna.osg` contains texture coordinates?

Comment: SurvivalMachine, you are right. But when trying with a model that it does, like the skydome.osgt, I get the model with its original texture, and not with the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good, but the cessna.osg model you're using definitely does not have any UV (texture) coordinates.

You can inspect the text version of the model (cessna.osgt) with a notepad and you'll see only vertex coords and not texture coords.

Run your test with any other model with texture coordinates. In the [osg-data repo](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph-Data) there are several, like skydome.osgt

Comment: Hi rickyviking, thank you very much for your quick answer. That may be the reason, but when I run again the code, now loading the skydome.osgt instead of cessna.osg, I am getting the skydome.osg with its original texture (a sky with clouds). 

Should I make any further modification in my code to get a skydome with the bricks texture?

Comment: Oh that's right, the texture specified in the loaded model's StateSet is being used instead of your, as it is below you node in the scenegraph. You can either remove its own texture from the text file or override the texture attribute with this call `ss->setTextureAttributeAndModes(0, bodyTexture.get(), osg::StateAttribute::ON | osg::StateAttribute::OVERRIDE);`